# Error when saving relative layout as bitmap using layout.getDrawingCache() returning null

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-camera, android-bitmap

How to handle full-sized photo using *MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT*? First, I need to put the picture AS FULL-SIZED NOT THUMBNAIL on a layout and put text below it like this:

[image]

The idea I am using is that I am using *layout.getDrawingCache* to make it as bitmap.

Below is my camera button:

```
private void SelectImage(){

    final CharSequence[] items={"Camera", "Cancel"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PickupDrop.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Image");

    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (items[i].equals("Camera")) {

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                if(cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null){

                    File imageFile = null;
                    try {
                        imageFile = getImageFile();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if(imageFile!= null){
                         imageUri =FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.android.fileprovider", imageFile);


                        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
                        cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,REQUEST_CAMERA);

                       
                    }

                }

            } else if (items[i].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();

}
```

The *getImageFile()* method:

```
private File getImageFile(){
    String imageName = "test";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File imageFile = null;
    try {
        imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageName,".jpg",storageDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    currentImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    return imageFile;
}
```

As you can see above, I am using EXTRA_OUTPUT with fileprovider to get FULL-SIZED bitmap.
Below is my manifests, provider.

Manifest:

```
<application ...
<provider
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_path"/>
    </provider>
```

file_path.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<external-path
    name="my images"
    path="Android/data/com.example.luckypasabayapp/files/Pictures"/>
```

My onActivityResult method:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);

    if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){

        if(requestCode==REQUEST_CAMERA){

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentImagePath);


            populateScreenshot(bitmap);

        

        }
    }
}
```

Now here is where my problem occurs when I try to save the relative layout *screenshot* to my storage:

```
public void populateScreenshot(Bitmap bitmapFromPhone){

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(PickupDrop.this);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.information_dialog, null);
    ImageView imageView_profilePic = v.findViewById(R.id.imageview_image);
    TextView txt_item_data = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_data);
    Button btn_cancel = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    Button btn_download = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_download);
    screenShot = v.findViewById(R.id.screenShot);
    screenShot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    screenShot.buildDrawingCache();

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PickupDrop.this)
            .setView(v)
            .create();

    alertDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // Prevent dialog close on back press button
            return keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK;
        }
    });
    //alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    
    
    
    
    //SETTING THE IMAGEVIEW OF LAYOUT TAKEN FROM CAMERA
    imageView_profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmapFromPhone);
    

    btn_download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //GETTING THE RELATIVELAYOUT AS BITMAP
            Bitmap bitmap = screenShot.getDrawingCache();
            

            File filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(filePath.getAbsolutePath()+"/qrcode/");

            dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, "str_specialNumber" + ".png");

            try {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            
            //HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS, IT SAYS BITMAP IS NULL!!!
            
            bitmap.setHasAlpha(true);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,outputStream);

            Toast.makeText(PickupDrop.this,"SCREENSHOT Downloaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                outputStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //notify gallery for a new picture
            galleryAddPic(filePath.getAbsolutePath()+"/qrcode/"+"str_specialNumber"+".png");


        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();



}
```

Here in *bitmap.setHasAlpha(true);* it says bitmap is null from *screenshot.getDrawingCache* I don't understand why.

How do I handle the EXTRA_OUTPUT properly to be able to do whatever I want with the bitmap?

Comment: do you mean how to take screenshot or bitmap of `RelativeLayout` right?

Comment: @VishalBeep yes, but even when i tried to save the bitmap alone (the on taken from camera, not the relativelayout as bitmap) it still return as null.

Answer (score 1):

You can give this answer a try :)

If you want to take the screenshot of any `view` or your `RelativeLayout` you can create this method `takeScreenShot()` : it will return a `Bitmap`
in `@Param` or parameter in this method, you can pass `RelativeLayout`

```
    public static Bitmap takeScreenShot(@NonNull View view) {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_AUTO);
    view.buildDrawingCache();

    if (view.getDrawingCache() == null) return null;
    Bitmap snapshot;
    try {
        snapshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        view.destroyDrawingCache();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        snapshot = null;
    }
    return snapshot;
}
```

tell me if this helps you :)

Comment: still returns null when I pass the screenshot layout :(

Comment: @Lawrence have tried this with another view for example `LinearLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: apparently I only need to write android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to my manifest